# How to get two inputs from a same input (C++)

Tags: c++

Title probably sounds confusing so first I'll show you my code, I made this simple program to get two input values and multiply them, and another thing, but that's not important, It works correctly:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main()
{
    int a,b,c,d,e;
    char j = 4;
    cout << "Welcome to Momentum Calculator\n\n";
    cout << "------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Please Enter Mass in KG (if the mass in in grams, put \"9999\" and hit enter): \n\n";
    cin >> a;
    if (a==9999) {
        cout << "\nPlease Enter Mass in grams: \n\n";
        cin >> d;
    }
    else {
        d = 0;
    }
    cout << "\nPlease Enter Velocity \n\n";
    cin >> e;
    if (d == 0)
    {
        c = (a*e);
    }
    else {
        c = (e*d)/100;
    }
    cout << "\nMomentum = " << c;
    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
    while (j == 4)
    {
        cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        main();
    }
}
```

Now as you can see, my variable is an int (integer) and my problem is If I enter an English letter (a-z) or anything that is not a number will cause it to repeat my program unlimited times at an unlimited speed. I want a string/char to see if my var "a" is a letter or anything but don't know how to. I can do it, however, I want user to input only one time in "a" and mine makes him to enter again. Please Help :)

Comment: Recursive call of `main` is wrong (you probably should add some `do`...`while`... outer loop), and you should declare it `int main(int argc, char**argv)` .... Also, compile with all warnings and debugging information (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`) and learn to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm a newbie and don't get what you mean? Can you help me in detail, or give me the code? Sorry for any inconvenience, for the debugging, I don't know that too :(
Neither do I know what to put in my do.. while :'(

Comment: You should find by yourself the code. You won't learn anything if we did your homework! And you can find a lot of interesting material on the web (and details are compiler and operating system specific; I hope you are using Linux, it is so fun and it is free software so you can study its source code).

Comment: `main` needs `int` as its return type (why bother with the parameters if you don't use them). Putting no return type is not legal. Using `main` in the program is also not legal. In addition to `-Wall`, I suggest `-Wextra -pedantic-errors`. I also suggest declaring variables as close to first use as you can.

Comment: As a first step remove the while loop completely. It has two problems: 1. it is an infinite loop (j will never be anything else than 4) 2. it is illegal to call `main()` recursively in your program.

Comment: I don't know if you mean homework in literal sense or not but It's not "really" my homework, for the code. I'd appreciate if you could give me the code, I'll try to observe and learn from it as now I literally have NO IDEA what to do or what to use...

Comment: @chris I have no idea what you said, if in the loop I do "int main()" It goes blank...

Comment: @Hulk 1) What is wrong with an infinite loop? It works correctly until I put in a letter 2) Okay, but I REALLY don't know any alternatives to going back to start and not restarting the program..

Comment: If you dont know yet about `do` ... `while` ... syntax in C, consider having two *nested* `while` loops, and learn to use your debugger to run your program step by step.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Hmm, I'll try to learn Debugging later, for now, I want to complete this code..

Comment: If you really don't know about such a simple thing as loops, yet, then you really need to spend more time with a basic C++ tutorial and stick to things which are simpler and that you *do* know. If you haven't yet put in enough effort to learn the basics, it's not fair to expect people on the internet to spoon feed you.

Comment: Learning to use a debugger is almost a necessary step to complete this code.... and is extremely useful for any future work in C++ coding... BTW, C++ is not the best language to start learning programming. I suggest Scheme and reading the famous [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) ....

Comment: @Yariz, You need `int main {...}` where you have `main() {...}`. The other place where you call `main` is not valid C++ because `main` cannot be used in a program. The compiler should stop you. If it doesn't, you need a higher warning level or a newer compiler. If you need to loop all of `main`, you can always add a loop to do everything again.

Comment: @chris I get it, thanks for your help. btw, I use the latest ver. of Dev C++ and I'd try to use a loop! Thanks again :)

Comment: Last I heard, Dev-C++ was *really* outdated and hasn't been updated for a long time. [This project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/) kind of took over it.

Comment: @chris So should I use Code::Blocks?

Comment: That's what I use when VS doesn't suit what I'm doing better, but I've never tried Orwell, so I can't comment on how good or bad it is. At least the compiler that comes with it should be pretty new. The CodeBlocks one is getting more behind as time goes on, but it's always possible to upgrade that separately.

Comment: Hmm. No matter how much I try, I can't fit in Code::Blocks, and too lazy to customize, (How I use Dec C++: http://prntscr.com/1qnfrp)

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called isalpha in ctype library, checks whether your variable is an alphabetic letter so you can do using isalpha function.

Answer (score 1):

Will isdigit or isalpha from standard library help you?

P.S.
1KG contains 1000 grams, so you should divide by 1000, not by 100;

UPDATE:
Seems I understood your question...
You need cin.clear(); before cin.get() and cin.ignore().
Otherwise the these calls won't do anything, as cin is in an error state.

Comment: That's just an example. I'm trying REALLY hard to do it but isn't working :(

Comment: main answer was updated. Please, check if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get a as an String, and see if it contains English letter or not, if it contains, again ask for the input ( you can do it in a while loop ). And when a correct input entered, parse it and find what is it's number.

Comment: You probably mean a `std::string` .... the `String` type is not in standard C++ ....